# how to make an application/x-executable file

Tags: linux

I need to make a file at which when run the command "file filename" it should show that it is an "application/x-executable" file

Comment: Try reading `man magic`

Comment: Why the downvotes? Why the _too broad_? AFAICT, `file` will only report that mime type for ELF executables, that can't be less broad.

Answer (score 7):

`file` reports that mime type for ELF executables (and ELF executables only it would seem at least with the version 5.22 I'm looking at).

So all you need is enough of a ELF file header for it to find a ELF executable. For instance:

```
printf '\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0' > file
```

What's important in there are:

- `\177ELF` that identifies it as a ELF file
- the `\2\0` that means *executable* (as opposed to shared library or other ELF file type).
- the first `\1` that tells it's little endian (if you change that to `\2`, then the `\2\0` has to be changed to `\0\2`).

All the rest you can change. You can for instance shorten it to `printf '\177ELF.\1%10s\2\0'`.

That includes the minimum required to be recognised as a ELF executable.

(`file --mime-type file` to show the mime type).

Or just grab those bytes from any of the ELF executables on your system:

```
head -c18 < /bin/ls > file
```

It goes without saying that it does not make those files valid ELF executables. It's just enough of the ELF file header for `file` to recognised them as ELF executables, not enough for your system to be able to execute them.

To make a small ELF executable that can still be executed, see [this guy's attempt](http://timelessname.com/elfbin/) at creating the smallest "Hi World" executable (for Linux on x86/amd64):

```
uudecode << EOF
begin-base64 755 file
f0VMRgEBAUhpIFdvcmxkCgIAAwABAAAAgIAECDQAAAAAuAQAAADNgOtYIAAC
ACgABQAEAAEAAAAAAAAAAIAECACABAiiAAAAogAAAAUAAAAAEAAAAQAAAKQA
AACkkAQIpJAECAkAAAAJAAAAugkAAAC5B5AECLsBAAAA66QAAADr6rsAAAAA
uAEAAADNgA==
====
EOF
```

Or from http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html (45 bytes!), that does nothing but exit with code 42:

```
uudecode << EOF
begin-base64 755 file
f0VMRgEAAAAAAAAAAAABAAIAAwAgAAEAIAABAAQAAACzKjHAQM2AADQAIAAB
====
EOF
```

Interestingly, Linux accepts to execute it as an ELF executable even though it's not a valid one (it's even shorter than a ELF header), and `file` does not report `application/x-executable` on it (because the endianness field is 0 instead of 1/2)